# Manage iOS automatic connection to public Wi-Fi

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi, skype

I use Skype to make some international calls. This works well if I am at home/office and connected to Wi-Fi.

However if I am on move, I prefer to turn off Wi-Fi to prevent connection to public Wi-Fi networks so that it won't affect my ongoing calls.

Sometimes after calls I forget to turn on Wi-Fi and start using some other app which can consume substantial amount of data.

Is there is any way to disconnect Wi-Fi for just a few minutes (the estimated duration of the call)? Or to force app calling features to use cellular only?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "prevent connection to public Wi-Fi"? What public networks is it connecting to?

Comment: It would help to know if these are just "random starbucks" or carrier-specific public access points. One is pref-controlled, the other is profile-controlled.

Comment: @Tetsujin These are some random starbucks kind of public access points.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than manually managing when you are connected to untrusted WiFi access points, you should consider setting up a VPN connection that is automatically enabled when you connect to WiFi.  That will protect your data - even when on a public WiFi network.  At that point, you don't need to worry as much about whether WiFi is on or off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will having a VPN prevent IOS from automatically connecting to wifi. I have a VPN setup on my phone . Also I have set Settings->wifi->Ask to join networks to Notify. It still connects to public network like starbucks etc.

Comment: I think you may have to tell it to forget structures it has previously connected to, then the pref should work.